# percentage padding inside ul li a "jumps" the LI

Tags: html-lists, href, padding

i'm creating this base structure :

```
<ul>
<li>
<a>
blabla

</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

with css :

```
ul{
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li{
  height: 25%;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

a{
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 75%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  padding-top:25%;
}
```

i can't manage to simply put the a at the bottom...
i thought giving the A a height of 25% and a padding of 75% would work but it takes 75% of the UL and not 75% of the LI.

anyone has an idea how come?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

If I am assuming correctly you want an `<li>` that is 25% the height of its container and the `<a>` to sit at the bottom-right of the `<li>`

If that is the case you could use this css

**updated RE comment** In this case we could use a `<span>` inside the `<a>` to position the text and set the `<a>` to fill the `<li>`

```
ul {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

li {
  height: 25%;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

and the html

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>blabla</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThisIsMe/QuVu4/2/)

Please note that for this to work you need to set `html, body { height:100%; }` or have a container with an explicit height set. i.e. `ul { height: 200px; }` or  `div.container { height: 200px; }`

I would also recommend applying the styles via classes.

Comment: well the problem is that, in that case, the "clickable" zone is very small....
that's why i needed its height to be equal to 100%, either using a padding or not...
here, the clickable zone is only limited by the height of the text...